# Validation loss increases after 3 epochs but validation accuracy keeps increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

Training and validation is healthy for 2 epochs but after 2-3 epochs the Val_loss keeps increasing while the Val_acc keeps increasing.

I'm trying to train a CNN model to classify a given review to a single class of 1-5. Therefore, I considered it as a multi-class classification.
I've divided the dataset to 3 sets - 70% training, 20% testing and 10% validation.

Distribution of training data for 5 classes as follows.

1 - 31613, 2 - 32527, 3 - 61044, 4 - 140005, 5 - 173023.

Therefore I've added class weights as follows.

{1: 5.47, 2: 5.32, 3: 2.83, 4: 1.26, 5: 1}

Model structure is as below.

```py
input_layer = Input(shape=(max_length, ), dtype='int32')

embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 200, input_length=max_length)(input_layer)

channel1 = Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=2, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(embedding)
channel1 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(channel1)

channel2 = Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(embedding)
channel2 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(channel2)

channel3 = Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=4, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(embedding)
channel3 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(channel3)

merged = concatenate([channel1, channel2, channel3], axis=1)

merged = Dense(256, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.6)(merged)
merged = Dense(5)(merged)
output = Activation('softmax')(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(final_X_train, final_Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=512, validation_data=(final_X_val, final_Y_val), callbacks=callback, class_weight=class_weights)
```

1/5 - loss: 1.8733 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: 0.7749 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.6558

2/5 - loss: 1.3908 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6917 - val_loss: 0.7421 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.6784

3/5 - loss: 0.9587 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7734 - val_loss: 0.7595 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.6947

4/5 - loss: 0.6402 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8370 - val_loss: 0.7921 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.7216

5/5 - loss: 0.4520 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8814 - val_loss: 0.8556 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.7331

Final accuracy = 0.7328754744261703

This seems to be an overfitting behavior, but I've tried adding dropout layers which didn't help. I've also tried increasing the data, which made the results even worst.

I'm totally new to deep learning, if anyone has any suggestions to improve, please let me know.

Comment: Increasing validation loss is perfectly fine as long as accuracy keeps improving. Google about cross-entropy loss if it is not clear. I would try to remove class weights. Although it is unbalanced, you still have relatively large amount of samples for every class. Instead, I would shuffle data at the beginning of every epoch and try to train longer than 5 epochs. Maybe 50-100 epochs.

Comment: I added an EarlyStopping to stop training once the val_categorical_accuracy starts dropping. I managed to train up to 9epochs and then val_accuracy started to decrease and the training stopped at 0.76 accuracy. After testing on testing set it gave a similar accuracy. But the loss kept increasing after 4epochs.

Answer (score 2):

**val_loss keeps increasing while the Val_acc keeps increasing** This is maybe because of the loss function...loss function is being calculated using actual predicted probabilities while accuracy is being calculated using one hot vectors.

Let's take your 4-class example. For one of the review **true** class is, say **1**. The predicted probabilities by the system are [0.25, 0.30, 0.25, 0.2]. According to **categorical_accuracy** your output is correct i.e [0, 1, 0, 0] but since your probability mass is so distributed...**categorical_crossentropy** will give a high loss as well.

As for the overfitting problem. I am not really sure why introducing more data is causing problems.

Try increasing the strides.
Don't make the data more imbalanced by adding data to any particular class.

Comment: I still have a doubt in selecting the best loss function for my scenario. I expect one output which should be a class from 1 to 5. Do you think using categorical_crossentropy is the best or maybe using mean_squared_error because I always use argmax to take the class with the highest probability in categorical_crossentropy ignoring the rest of the classes with low probabilities?

Comment: **mean_squared_error** is not recommended in multi-class classification problems. I think you should use **categorical_crossentropy** only. You should read up about more combinations of **activation and loss functions** recommended for multi-class classifications(single and multi-label).